# Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable.. error occured

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, jxl

I'm trying to run some code on Android that uses an external library JXL.

I add the required jar to my build path and  shows that there are no errors. When I attempt to run the program on Android I get this error in LogCat.

> Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable

and this is my build.gradle

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.shale.gps_test"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguar d-android.txt'),          'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
```

}

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I am having the same problem, Android 4.4.4. My app freezes and then after a minute crashes.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: nop. sorry for late answer:(